# How do I make the Nikon D7000 rear LCD show just status information and settings rather than the live view?

Tags: camera-settings, nikon-d7000, display

I've recently bought a Nikon D7000, and I've been watching tutorials and tips and reading the manual on how to use it, but one thing is bugging me and I'm unable to find or realize the solution, on my display (the big LCD) I see the image that is seen through my lens and some information like focal and so on.
This is the image of a screenshot, what I want it to show:

[image]

I press the button `info` but it changes the information displayed a bit, but doesn't make the image go away and just show the same. How can I make it look like the one in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see the captured image in the LCD screen after each capture, you should set Image Review to "Off" (`Menu` button > `Playback` menu > `Image Review` > `Off`). Refer to page 200 of the [D7000 user guide](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D7000_ENnoprint.pdf). Note that with Image Review turned off, nothing will appear on the screen after you take a photo. You will have to manually turn on the information display (`info`) button.

If a captured image is displayed on the screen, to make it go away, press the **Playback button** (▶️). After that, you can press the `info` button to see the information display.

At any time, to see the information display, press the `info` button. Press the `info` button twice more, or half-press the shutter button, to turn off the information display. (pp. 10–11 of the user guide).

You can change how long the information display stays on, before it automatically turns off, under the Custom Settings "Monitor off Delay" menu: `Menu` button > `Custom Settings` > `c4: Monitor off Delay` > `Information display`. It defaults to 10 seconds, but can be set shorter or longer, or even made to never turn off automatically. (p. 215 of the user guide).